# Create a local date from a UTC date string in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, utc

Given a UTC date string (formatted: YYYYMMDDHHmmss) I'd like to create a date with the local timezone using Moment.js. I have tried the following:

```
var utcDateStr = '20140101120000';
var localDate = moment.utc(utcDateStr, 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss');

//actual: true
//desired: false
console.log(localDate._isUTC)

//actual: "Wed Jan 01 2014 12:00:00 GMT+0000"
//desired: "Wed Jan 01 2014 07:00:00 GMT-0500"
console.log(localDate.toString())
```

How do I create a date that is formatted in the local time zone by default when I call `toString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`.local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) function, added in version 1.5.0.

```
var localDate = moment.utc(utcDateStr, 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').local();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// UTC time
var utcDateStr = '20140101120000';

// First way
var offset = moment().utcOffset();
var localtime = moment.utc(utcDateStr,'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').utcOffset(offset);

// Another way
var anotherLocaltime= moment.utc(utcDateStr, 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').local();
```

Both the way works just fine... See the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahim373/L0gcL0td/)